# Can't hide innerHTML after error corrected

Tags: javascript, html

Didn't see an answer so here goes. Error messages are using innerHTML. How do I get them to disappear once the error is corrected? Right now it just stays on. I tried resetting at the top of the script.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/justinae/tX5y5/)

HTML:

```
<form id="contact" name="contact" onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" action="" method="post">
            <h2>Contact Me</h2>
    <div id="main-error"></div>     
    <div>
                <label>Name</label>
                <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" name="name" id="name" tabindex="1" autofocus />
                <div id="name-error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" autofocus />
                <div id="email-error"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Phone</label>
                <input placeholder="Phone" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="4" autofocus />
                <div id="test"></div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5">Send</button>
            </div>

        </form>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML='';
document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML='';
document.getElementById('phone-error').innerHTML='';

function validateFormOnSubmit(contact) { 
    var reason = "";

  reason += validateEmail(contact.email);
  reason += validatePhone(contact.phone);
  reason += validateEmpty(contact.name);

  if (reason != "") {
    document.getElementById("main-error").innerHTML="Test main error message area";
    return false;
  }

  return false;
}

// validate required fields
function validateEmpty(name) {
    var error = "";

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        name.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML="The required field has not been filled in";
    } else {
        name.style.background = 'White';
    }
    return error;   
}


// validate email as required field and format
function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
} 

function validateEmail(email) {
    var error="";
    var temail = trim(email.value);                        // value of field with whitespace trimmed off
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
    var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;

    if (email.value == "") {
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Please enter an email address.";
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(temail)) {              //test email for illegal characters
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address.";
    } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Email contains invalid characters.";
    } else {
        email.style.background = 'White';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate phone for required and format
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');     

   if (phone.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="Please enter a phone number"; 
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (!(stripped.length == 10)) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 
    return error;
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Move the "clearing" code into the main function so that it is run each time to remove error messages, or add an else block like: `if (reason != "") {...} else { /*clear error messages*/ }`

Comment: that seems like it would work but doesn't in JSfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function validateFormOnSubmit(contact) { 
    reason = "";
 reason += validateEmpty(contact.name);
  reason+= validateEmail(contact.email);


    reason+= validatePhone(contact.phone);

    console.log(reason);
  if ( reason.length>0 ) {

    return false;
  }

    else {
        return true;
    }


}

// validate required fields
function validateEmpty(name) {
    var error = "";

    if (name.value.length == 0) {
        name.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML="The required field has not been filled in";
        var error = "1";
    } else {
        name.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('name-error').innerHTML='';
    }
    return error;   
}


// validate email as required field and format
function trim(s)
{
  return s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');
} 

function validateEmail(email) {
    var error="";
    var temail = trim(email.value);                        // value of field with whitespace trimmed off
    var emailFilter = /^[^@]+@[^@.]+\.[^@]*\w\w$/ ;
    var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/ ;

    if (email.value == "") {
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Please enter an email address.";
        var error="2";
    } else if (!emailFilter.test(temail)) {              //test email for illegal characters
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Please enter a valid email address.";
        var error="3";
    } else if (email.value.match(illegalChars)) {
        email.style.background = 'Yellow';
        var error="4";
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML="Email contains invalid characters.";
    } else {
        email.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('email-error').innerHTML='';
    }
    return error;
}

// validate phone for required and format
function validatePhone(phone) {
    var error = "";
    var stripped = phone.value.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');     

   if (phone.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="Please enter a phone number"; 
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
       var error = '6';
    } else if (isNaN(parseInt(stripped))) {
        var error="5";
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="The phone number contains illegal characters.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } else if (stripped.length < 10) {
        var error="6";
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="The phone number is too short.";
        phone.style.background = 'Yellow';
    } 

    else {
       phone.style.background = 'White';
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML='';
    }
    return error;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tX5y5/59/

I have just changed place of inner html cleaning... and i have added some changes in whole validation (it didn't worked before properly).

Comment: THANKS! I don't know what you did but it works now. I was banging my head against the wall. What changes did you make so I can learn. Thanks again!

Comment: So it works great in JSfiddle but my live environment when I click "Send" it just reloads the page even though all fields are empty. I changed the main return to false just like in JSfiddle. Do I need to set that back to true?

Comment: @justinae—the listener should return whatever the function returns (as in your OP `<form ... onsubmit="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" ...>`. The validation function should return `false` if validation fails so that submission is cancelled. Returning any other value (including `null` or `undefined`) will not stop the form submitting. So usually `false` is returned if validation fails and nothing (i.e. `undefined`) if it succeeds.

Comment: @justinae, i hope you've solved problem - simple - set action attribute to form (php page where data will be processed), and it will work. Btw, DO NOT rely on client side validation - it can be easily bypassed - always validate data on server side. I tried to leave your code as close as possible to original...What i have added... error var, basically - which will be returned from your validation functions and added/sent to your main function (reason var). If reason var is empty (no errors) -> send form! hope it is clear(er) now... :)P.S. Check console log (F12 in FF) to see value of reason

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to register a listener for when the user changes one of your input fields and run your validation function in the listener. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('name').addEventListener("change", validateFormOnSubmit);
document.getElementById('email').addEventListener("change", validateFormOnSubmit);
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener("change", validateFormOnSubmit);
```

[If at all possible I'd recommend using an existing library for form validation (but you probably already knew that).](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Form.html)

Comment: The OP already has validation for when the form is submitted, the issue is that the error messages aren't being cleared if a control that formerly failed validation passes when validated again.